# How can I scrolling horizeontal and vertical

Tags: css, scroll, skrollr

I want to fix and horizontally scrolling with bg class.
And make top:0; with panels class.
I want to these scrolling.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsVbd.png)
And I want to make like it.
How can I solve this problem?
I use skrollr.js

HTML

```
 <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="panels" style="background-color:deeppink">Panel 1</div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="bg" style="background-color:red"
                 data-0="transform:translate3d(0%,0%,0); opacity:1"
                 data-5000="transform:translate3d(-100%,0%,0); opacity:0">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panels" style="background-color:orange">Panel 2</div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
.panels {
    top: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 10px;
}
.container {
    background-color: black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: This is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/09wyzte5/124/)

Comment: This is my [omajuo](http://akita.co.uk/movement-of-data/).